# Flutter, Dart, Firebase: The Method [] was called on null. Works one time the next an error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am getting the following error, when I execute my code.
Yesterday it was working just fine, I changed nothing in the code.

> I/flutter (22418): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on
> null. I/flutter (22418): Receiver: null I/flutter (22418): Tried calling: [] ('ID')

**Code**

```
 onPressed: () async {
                              try {
                                var userDetail =
                                    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(uid).get();
                                String ID = userDetail.data()['ID'];
                                String Name = userDetail.data()['Name'];
                                String Number =
                                    userDetail.data()['Phone Number'];
                                String gender =
                                    userDetail.data()['Gender'];
                                firestore
                                    .collection('Appointments')
                                    .doc(ID)
                                    .set({
                                  'Doctor Name': widget.user['Name'],
                                  'Doctor Speciality': widget.speciality,
                                  'Name': Name,
                                  'User ID': ID,
                                  'Number': Number,
                                  'Gender':gender,
                                  'Date of Appointment': {
                                    'Day': day,
                                    'Date': date,
                                    'Month': thismonth,
                                  },
                                  'Time Of Appointment': {
                                    'Time': time,
                                    'Time Range': timeRange,
                                  }
                                });
```

Can you please help me understand what went wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check I think userDetail is null

```
var userDetail =await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(uid).get();
```

Comment: It is not Null I just checked it using .exists

Comment: Sorry, Just rechecked it it is null, but it shows information in my firestore